# mirrors for rpmforge repository

Tags: centos, yum, repository

As I run `yum makecache` on Centos-6.1, I get this error:

```
epel-source/other_db                                                          | 1.6 MB     00:40
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/mirrors-rpmforge error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404"
http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/x86_64/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: rpmforge. Please verify its path and try again
```

So, there is a problem with rpmforge and in fact `http://apt.sw.be` is down. Any way to fix that?

Comment: please see updated version of my answer

Answer (score 1):

Download the appropriate **rpmforge package** [here](http://repoforge.org/use/) if you need the source.

Then run this for **64 bit**:

```
wget http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
```

And for **32 bit**:

```
wget http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.i686.rpm
rpm -Uvh rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.i686.rpm
```

Add the key for the above **repo**:

```
wget http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
rpm --import RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
```

Go [here](http://www.tecmint.com/enable-rpmforge-repository/) for more information and [here](https://www.unixmen.com/install-repoforge-rpmforge-repository-rhel-centos-scientific-linux-76-x5-x4-x/) for the same repo as yours which is older than the former given above.

Comment: So, should I remove the rpmforge* from /etc/yum.repo.d ?

Comment: no the __system__ should do it for you.

Comment: please see updated version of my answer

Comment: Still after 10 hours, I am not able to see `http://packages.sw.be`. Do you? It doesn't either working on web browser. Just want to know if it is my problem (network) or not.

Comment: let me install it myself and get back to you, sorry for the situation

Comment: There is definitely a problem with that repo as I can't also reach it. Try their [official forum](https://www.centos.org/forums/) for further help. Mean while you could disable it.